# rm: cannot remove 'test123': Permission denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, rm

*I use this command but it didn't work*

```
rm test123
```

**note 1** :

```
menna@ubuntu:/etc$ l -ltr
total 1116

drwxr-xr-x  7 root  root    4096 Mar 18 06:11 apparmor.d/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root    4096 Mar 18 06:11 firefox/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root    4096 Mar 18 06:11 ssh/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root    4096 Mar 18 08:01 cron.daily/
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  root    1063 Mar 18 08:01 group
-rw-r-----  1 root  shadow   886 Mar 18 08:01 gshadow
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root    4096 Mar 18 23:56 ImageMagick-6/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root    4096 Mar 18 23:56 alternatives/
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   47812 Mar 18 23:56 mailcap
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root   65910 Mar 18 23:56 ld.so.cache
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  lp      4096 Mar 19 05:14 cups/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 menna menna      0 Mar 19 06:48 test123*
```

**note 2**: I give the file "test123" all the permissions

**note 3:**menna@ubuntu:/etc$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root 12288 Mar 19 06:48 /etc

Comment: This is your second question with downvotes. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to provide specific detail. You might also take the opportunity at the same time to learn how to structure your question to make it readable.

Comment: You need to be root to create or remove files in `/etc`. This is not really related to Ubuntu, but basic Posix filesystem knowledge.

Comment: Do you have rights to delete files in / etc ? Please update your question with the output of `ls -ld /etc` .

Comment: @ArturMeinild but i changed the owner of the file test123 .. I did it menna

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the output you are receiving is a "Permission Denied" error as you are trying to delete a file in the `etc` directory which is owned by root.

When deleting a file, you aren't modifying the file itself, however, you are modifying the contents of the directory. So in order to delete the file, you need to have a user that has "write" permission on the *directory* not the file.

Since you're in the `/etc` directory and since you shouldn't modify permission of the `/etc` directory then you need to use the `root` user in order to delete the file.

So in order to delete the file, you need to run the `rm` command with `sudo`.

```
sudo rm test123
```